# Please rename tag [bluemix-appid] to to [ibm-appid]

Tags: support, status-completed, retag-request

We want to rename the tag [bluemix-appid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bluemix-appid) to [ibm-appid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ibm-appid) on Stack Overflow. The name of the referenced service is being rebranded to **App ID** and it is available through IBM at the following URL: https://console.bluemix.net/catalog/services/app-id

Can one of the moderators make the change please?

Comment: Done. I've left bluemix-appid as a synonymn pointing towards ibm-appid for people that are use to typing bluemix...

Comment: @Bill, this is why I asked you to MSO instead of MSE. You will get faster response from per site moderators

Comment: Jon & @sagarV Thank you for your assistance! It's very much appreciated!

Comment: Hey @BillWentworth, what does IBM team think of this request -- https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359376/rename-data-science-experience ? What's your position?