# Rename [data-science-experience] to [ibm-data-science-experience]

Tags: discussion, tags, retag-request, synonym-request, tag-disambiguation

[data-science-experience](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/data-science-experience) is related to IBM Data Science Experience, as stated in its excerpt:

> IBM Data Science Experience is an interactive, collaborative,
>   cloud-based environment where data scientists can use multiple tools
>   to activate their insights. Data scientists can use the best of open
>   source, tap into IBM's unique features, grow their capabilities, and
>   share their successes. Source:
>   http://datascience.ibm.com/blog/welcome-to-the-data-science-experience/

I think it makes sense to rename it to [ibm-data-science-experience](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ibm-data-science-experience), or even make it a synonym for [ibm-data-science-experience](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ibm-data-science-experience), because right now it looks like general meta/broad tag like [computer-science](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/computer-science) or [data-science](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/data-science). I've even thought it was created by mistake at first (somebody created a tag for asking about somebody's experience in Data Science).

Comment: Note that we also could make [tag:dsx] the main tag. It's a synonym now, and related tags like [tag:dsx-local] and [tag:dsx-desktop] already refer to  data science experience as dsx, and so do many questions. It also avoids the very long tag and the confusion between a general subject.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth I'm not an expert in this, so I don't really know.

Comment: What is it about IBM that makes them so special that they need their company name in the tags?  We, say, don't prefix [apple-] or [microsoft-] to tags that cover their technology and products, please explain why that should be different for IBM.

Comment: @HansPassant Because this tag seems like a general CS concept if you take a quick look. [tag:ios] is not prefixed with `apple-` because it is an unique thing. But for example, we have [tag:ms-project] for Microsoft Project to prevent confusion with general [tag:project] tag, which can mean multiple things.

Comment: @HansPassant Also, official name of this is IBM Data Science Experience. Not like Android, or iOS.

Comment: We try to use a general tag if it is available so we are not creating new tags. That's what was done in this case. Teams within IBM are required to follow tags for their service on the IBM Cloud platform. I'd prefer to leave it "as is." However, if you believe it would be better to preface the tag with ibm, that is fine with us. However, I will need to make some adjustments internally to ensure that questions are followed. How would that affect metrics through the SO API?